# pandas - set value based on NOT being a particular index integer and column value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, filter

suppose I have a datafrate df1:

```
   Color Saturation Letter
0  red        90       B
7  green      90       B
2  blue       90       A
7  red        90       B
2  green      90       B
7  red        90       A
```

and I want to set the value of `Saturation` equal to `1` only for rows where the index is not equal to `7` and `Letter` is equal to `A`

So that we get:

```
  Color Saturation Letter
    0  red        90       B
    7  green      90       B
    2  blue       1        A
    7  red        90       B
    2  green      90       B
    7  red        90       A
```

How might one do this?
I've attempted 
    `df.loc[df['Letter']=='A' & df.index != 7, 'Saturation'] =1` and `!df.iloc[7]` but I cannot seem to pinpoint the 'non-indices' properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `.loc`

```
df.loc[(df.Letter=='A')&~(df.index==7),'Saturation ']=1
```

Answer (score 0):

just as soon as I post the question, I've determined the answer:

```
df.loc[df['Letter']==A & ~df.index.isin([7]), "Saturation"] =1
```